# tmhOauth update_with_media using hashtag forbidden

Tags: php, twitter

i am using tmhOauth library to post status to twitter.

why I got `403` when i try update_with_media with a hashtag inside it. below is full code.

```
session_start();
require 'tmhOAuth.php';

$tmhOAuth = new tmhOAuth(array(
    'consumer_key'              => 'MYKEY',
    'consumer_secret'           => 'MYSECRET',
    'curl_ssl_verifypeer'       => false
));

if(isset($_GET['oauth_verifier'])){
    $tmhOAuth->config['user_token']  = $_SESSION['oauth']['oauth_token'];
    $tmhOAuth->config['user_secret'] = $_SESSION['oauth']['oauth_token_secret'];

    $code = $tmhOAuth->request(
        'POST',
        $tmhOAuth->url('oauth/access_token', ''),
        array(
          'oauth_verifier' => $_GET['oauth_verifier']
        )
    );

    if($code == 200){
        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $tmhOAuth->extract_params($tmhOAuth->response['response']);

        $tmhOAuth->config['user_token']  = $_SESSION['access_token']['oauth_token'];
        $tmhOAuth->config['user_secret'] = $_SESSION['access_token']['oauth_token_secret'];

        $base64_data = file_get_contents($_SESSION['twitter_image_data']);

        $status = <<<EOD

You can see yourself at Catholic U, too! Go to somelink.com to check out this cool app!
#hashtag
EOD;

        echo strlen($status);
        $params = array(
            'media[]' => "{$base64_data};type=image/jpeg;filename=myimage.jpg",
            'status'  => $status
        );

        $response = $tmhOAuth->user_request(array(
            'method' => 'POST',
            'url' => $tmhOAuth->url("1.1/statuses/update_with_media"),
            'params' => $params,
            'multipart' => true
        ));

        print_r($response);

        if($response == 200){
            ?>
            <pre>Your image has been uploaded to twitter. this window will be closed in 3 seconds...</pre>
            <script>
                setTimeout(function(){
                    window.close();
                }, 3000);
            </script>
            <?php
        }

        unset($_SESSION['oauth']);
        unset($_SESSION['twitter_image_data']);
    }
}
```

anyway to debug it? `$response` only return response number. please help

Answer (score 1):

You are having a 403 error which happens when accessing the page or resource you were trying to reach is forbidden for some reason. You should check for url errors and make sure you're specifying an actual web page file name and extension, not just a directory.

Comment: it seems twitter update_with_media only allowing 108 char for status, i tried to truncate some text from status and it works well.

Comment: It makes sense, some websites include the 403 error also for forbidden (restricted) data. A good way to figure out what is going on is accesing the 403 error with internet explorer because ie shows the extension of the error like for example: 403.14. You can see a list of all errors and extensions here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943891